# Cross-compiling python extensions under Linux using distutils

Tags: c++, python, swig, distutils, mingw32

Is there any way to compile both Windows and Linux versions of Python/distutils/SWIG/C++ extensions under Linux? As far as I understand the problem is at least in obtaining windows version of python-dev.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two ways:

> 1. Install [MingW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW) on your linux system, and [cross-compile the extension](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2008-July/009724.html) using it
> 2. Compile it in a Windows Virtual Machine (eg. Windows7 on [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/))

I prefer the second option as it gives the opportunity to test that your program is working